# How do I avoid empty submission of file upload if none was selected?

Tags: php, forms

I have a editing form where I edit the item info I added previously with a form in add_item.php. The problem now with the editing form is that I want to be able to edit the item info without having to re-upload the same image so that it doesn't get removed. If I upload a new image, it works fine. But if I don't upload any image, it will submit the upload form with no upload at all and thus overwriting the old one.

How do I prevent empty submission of the file upload input if no new file was selected?

PHP:

```
$img=imageUpload('image');
        if(!$img) $img='';
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="upld" name="image">
<img src=".'.$Info_Item['img'].'" alt="no img">
```

Comment: Ok. But, show us your code which you are using for submitting the edit info..

Comment: Use `required` on the form field if you're using HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `isset`

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
//code 
}else{
echo 'select image';
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve anything, the image still gets removed if I don't reupload it again

Comment: better yet, if `empty()`.

Comment: Can u please give me a full code? I've no idea what else to do other than pasting your code and seeing if it works..I'm new to the whole PHP thing..

Comment: @BigSox SO isn't a free coding service, if you don't know how to do something you try and you learn.

Comment: try this code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm @BigSox

Answer (score 1):

Try this condition on your edit

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){ //checking if image is uploaded or not

    $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name']; //your file name
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png"); //assigninig the file types

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){ //checking the file types
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){ //checking file size is less than 2 MB
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name); //move your files to a folder
     echo "Success";
  }
  else{
     print_r($errors);
  }

}
if($file_name == "") //if your file name is empty that is you didn't upload file
{
  //your update query without image column
}
else
{
  //your update query with image column
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: *"`if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){` //checking if image is uploaded or not."* - That only checks if it's "not empty". Checking if it was uploaded is a different animal altogether `is_uploaded_file()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

supposing you're using a form, the better solution is to use the following check :

```
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_FILES['image'])){
 //your code here
}
```